# Gradient of a dot product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The wikipedia formula for the gradient of a dot product is given as

$$\nabla(a\cdot b) = (a\cdot\nabla)b +(b\cdot \nabla)a + a\times(\nabla\times b)+ b\times (\nabla \times a)$$

However, I also found the formula $$\nabla(a\cdot b) = (\nabla a)\cdot b + (\nabla b)\cdot a  $$

So... what is going on here?  The second formula seems much easier.  Are these equivalent?

Comment: are they from the same article? Which is to say, where did you get these?

Comment: It bears mentioning that the second formula works for any combination of dimensions, while the first works only when $a,b$ are $3$-vectors and you are taking the gradient with respect to a $3$-vector.

Comment: Gradient is a vector and the second formula is scalar. It can not be right.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo, Gradient is a vector, and the second formula IS a vector, since $\nabla a$ is a dyadic.

Comment: One may have a look at the original [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Vector_dot_product)

Comment: Shouldn't you say what $a$ and $b$ are meant to be, scalar or vector?

Answer (score 27):

They are basically the same. For the first identity, you could refer to my proof using Levi-Civita notation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467924/vector-calculus-identities-using-differential-forms/501237#501237). And for the second, you should know that 
$\nabla a=\left(\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}\right)^T$ is a matrix and dot product is exactly matrix multiplication. So the proof is
$$(\nabla a)\cdot b+(\nabla b)\cdot a=\left(\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i}b_j+\frac{\partial b_j}{\partial x_i}a_j\right)e_i=\frac{\partial(a_jb_j)}{\partial x_i}e_i=\nabla(a\cdot b)$$

Comment: Wouldn't the last expression become $(\nabla(a\cdot b))_i$? (Otherwise you're loosing the $i$)

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Strictly speaking, I missed $e_i$ in the middle expressions.

Comment: @Shuchang: In fact, they are vastly different since in the first formula $a$ and $b$ are *vector fields* (and the dot means *"scalar product"*), while in the second formula $a$ and $b$ are *functions* and the dot is the usual *product of functions*.

Comment: @AlexM. Am I right in thinking this is a problem with syntax. That they evaluate to the same thing but are not syntactically equivalent?

Comment: @AlexM. This answer assumes $a$ is a vector field in both formulae.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: It is not our job to try to guess what the poster meant. In any case, if $a$ and $b$ are vector fields as you say, then $a \cdot b$ is a function, and the gradient is not defined for functions (i.e. the notation $\nabla (a \cdot b)$ does not make sense, unless $\nabla$ is meant to be the Levi-Civita connection, which I *strongly* doubt).

Comment: @Alex M. You've guessed what the poster meant in assuming that $a$ doesn't have the same meaning in both statements. And of course the gradient is defined for functions, which $a\cdot b$ is regardless of interpretation-I have no idea what you're getting at with that comment.

Comment: This book https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Continuum-Mechanics-Mathematics-Engineering/dp/0123097509 in Ch.4 pp 30 says $\nabla (a\cdot b)=(\nabla a)^T b + (\nabla b)^T a$

Comment: @zed111 I think that is just notation confusion. He/she is using \nabla as derivative and not Gradient. When used for scalar functions, gradient is the transpose of the derivative. So, yes the book is correct.

Comment: @Shuchang I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm a beginner in vector calculus. I've learnt that ∇ can be treated as a vector with "empty" partial derivative operators. Treating ∇ as a vector, if I expand the right hand side of the first identity using the expansion of vector triple product, I get twice the left hand side. I clearly see that I have a misconception, and I do not know where to look this up. I did not post this as a question because I guessed it would be trivial. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @UmeshKonduru It'd be better for me to help if you can type your deduction here. But I guess at somewhere your ∇ applies to the wrong vector

Comment: @Shuchang I used a x (∇ x b) = (a.b)∇ - (a.∇)b on the RHS of the first identity

Comment: Okay, I think I've found answers to my questions on the internet. I had a lot of misconceptions.

Comment: @Shuchang, a and b are column vectors and j is their row index but j is also the column index of the "transposed Jacobian matrix" $\nabla a$? Then I think that you should write $(\nabla a)b$ for the matrix multiplication.

However, I find that confusing. I suggest using $i$ as the row index and having $\nabla a = \left(\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}\right)$ (standard Jacobian matrix), with $\cdot$ working vertically, separately for each column. Then you have to add transpose to your formula to have a column vector as the result. (Not perfectly nice, either.)

Comment: Best to have $i$ as the row index (unlike above) and having $(\nabla a)_{ij} = \frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}$ (the standard Jacobian matrix), with $c\cdot d := c^{\rm T}d$ (even if $c$ is a matrix). Then the column vectors $a,b$ produce directly the correct column vector $(\nabla) a\cdot b + (\nabla b)\cdot a$ as the result, without any fuss.

Answer (score 14):

Since there are not many signs that one may easily use in mathematical notations, many of these symbols are *overloaded*. In particular, the dot "$\cdot$" is used in the first formula to denote the *scalar product* of two *vector fields* in $\mathbb R^3$ called $a$ and $b$, while in the second formula it denotes the *usual product of the functions* $a$ and $b$. This means that both formulae are valid, but each one is so only in its proper context.

(It is scary to see that the answers and comments that were *wrong* collected the most votes!)

Comment: If they were scalar functions, the second identity would say simply $\nabla(ab)=b\nabla a+a\nabla b$ ; no need for dots or parentheses. The Wikipedia link does show a direct "$=$" between the two formulas (with slightly different notation), showing that $a$ and $b$ are still vectors.

Comment: @Alex M. Please improve your answer. Please expand and elucidate on, " This means that both formulae are valid, but each one is so only in its proper context."

Answer (score 5):

The second equation presented by you, $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \bigl( \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) = \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{a} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \, + \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{a}$, is the primary one and it is pretty easy to derive (*

*) here I use the same notation as I did in my previous answers [divergence of dyadic product using index notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977189/divergence-of-dyadic-product-using-index-notation/3320811#3320811) and [Gradient of cross product of two vectors (where first is constant)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214365/gradient-of-cross-product-of-two-vectors-where-first-is-constant/3226713#3226713)

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} \bigl( \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \!
\, = \, \boldsymbol{r}^i \partial_i \bigl( \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \!
\, = \, \boldsymbol{r}^i \bigl( \partial_i \boldsymbol{a} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \, + \, \boldsymbol{r}^i \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \bigl( \partial_i \boldsymbol{b} \bigr)
\, = \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{r}^i \partial_i \boldsymbol{a} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \, + \, \boldsymbol{r}^i \bigl( \partial_i \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{a} \, =$$
$$= \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{a} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \, + \, \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{a}$$

Again, I use the expansion of nabla as linear combination of cobasis vectors with coordinate derivatives ${\boldsymbol{\nabla} \! = \boldsymbol{r}^i \partial_i}$ (as always ${\partial_i \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}}$), the product rule for $\partial_i$ and the commutativity of dot product of any two vectors (for sure, coordinate derivative of some vector $\boldsymbol{w}$, $\partial_i \boldsymbol{w} \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial q^i} \boldsymbol{w} \equiv \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}{\partial q^i}$, is a vector and not some more complex tensor) – here ${\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \bigl( \partial_i \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) = \bigl( \partial_i \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \cdot \boldsymbol{a}}$. Again, I swap multipliers to get full nabla $\boldsymbol{\nabla}$ at the second term

For your first equation, the one with cross products, I need to mention the completely asymmetric isotropic Levi-Civita (pseudo)tensor of third complexity, ${^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}$

$${^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} = \boldsymbol{r}_i \times \boldsymbol{r}_j \cdot \boldsymbol{r}_k \; \boldsymbol{r}^i \boldsymbol{r}^j \boldsymbol{r}^k = \boldsymbol{r}^i \times \boldsymbol{r}^j \cdot \boldsymbol{r}^k \; \boldsymbol{r}_i \boldsymbol{r}_j \boldsymbol{r}_k$$

or in orthonormal basis with mutually perpendicular unit vectors $\boldsymbol{e}_i$

$${^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} = \boldsymbol{e}_i \times \boldsymbol{e}_j \cdot \boldsymbol{e}_k \; \boldsymbol{e}_i \boldsymbol{e}_j \boldsymbol{e}_k = \;\epsilon_{ijk}\! \boldsymbol{e}_i \boldsymbol{e}_j \boldsymbol{e}_k$$

(some more details about this (pseudo)tensor can be found at [Question about cross product and tensor notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957933/question-about-cross-product-and-tensor-notation/3222006#3222006))

Any cross product, including “curl” (a cross product with nabla), can be represented via dot products with the Levi-Civita (pseudo)tensor (**

**) it is pseudotensor because of $\pm$, being usually assumed “$+$” for “left-hand” triplet of basis vectors (where ${\boldsymbol{e}_1 \times \boldsymbol{e}_2 \cdot \boldsymbol{e}_3 \equiv \;\epsilon_{123} \: = -1}$) and “$-$” for “right-hand” triplet (where ${\epsilon_{123} \: = +1}$)

$$\pm \, \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{b} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \, {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} = {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \! \cdot \, \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b}$$

For the pair of cross products that “pseudo” is compensated. As the very relevant example

$$\boldsymbol{a} \times \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \! \times \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) = \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \, {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \, \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \, {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) = \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \, {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \, \bigl( {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \! \cdot \, \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) = \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \, {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \! \cdot \, \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b}$$

Now I’m going to dive into components, and I do it by measuring tensors using some orthonormal basis (${\boldsymbol{a} = a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a}$, ${\boldsymbol{b} = b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b}$, ${\boldsymbol{\nabla} \! = \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n}$, ...)

$$\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \, {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot {^3\!\boldsymbol{\epsilon}} \cdot \! \cdot \, \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b}
= a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a \; \cdot \epsilon_{ijk}\! \boldsymbol{e}_i \boldsymbol{e}_j \boldsymbol{e}_k \; \cdot \epsilon_{pqr}\! \boldsymbol{e}_p \boldsymbol{e}_q \boldsymbol{e}_r \cdot \! \cdot \, \boldsymbol{e}_n \left( \partial_n b_b \right) \boldsymbol{e}_b
= a_a \! \epsilon_{ajk}\! \boldsymbol{e}_j \!\epsilon_{kbn}\! \left( \partial_n b_b \right)$$

There’s a relation (too boring to derive it one more time) for contraction of two Levi-Civita tensors, saying

$$\epsilon_{ajk} \epsilon_{kbn} \: = \: \bigl( \delta_{ab} \delta_{jn} \! - \delta_{an} \delta_{jb} \bigr)$$

Thence

$$a_a \! \epsilon_{ajk} \epsilon_{kbn}\! \left( \partial_n b_b \right) \boldsymbol{e}_j
= \, a_a \bigl( \delta_{ab} \delta_{jn} \! - \delta_{an} \delta_{jb} \bigr) \! \left( \partial_n b_b \right) \boldsymbol{e}_j
= \, a_a \delta_{ab} \delta_{jn} \! \left( \partial_n b_b \right) \boldsymbol{e}_j
- a_a \delta_{an} \delta_{jb} \! \left( \partial_n b_b \right) \boldsymbol{e}_j =$$
$$= \, a_b \! \left( \partial_n b_b \right) \boldsymbol{e}_n
- \, a_n \! \left( \partial_n b_b \right) \boldsymbol{e}_b
= \left( \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n b_b \right) a_b
- \, a_n \! \left( \partial_n b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b \right)
= \left( \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b \right) \cdot a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a
- \, a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a \! \cdot \left( \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b \right)$$

Back to the direct invariant tensor notation

$$\left( \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b \right) \cdot a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a = \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{a}$$

$$a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a \! \cdot \left( \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b \right) = \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr)$$

Sure, the latter one can also be written as

$$\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \!
\, = \, a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a \! \cdot \left( \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b \right)
\, = \, \left( a_a \boldsymbol{e}_a\! \cdot \boldsymbol{e}_n \partial_n \right) b_b \boldsymbol{e}_b
\, = \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla} \bigr) \boldsymbol{b}$$

And finally (***

***) it looks like meanwhile I also answered to [Formula of the gradient of vector dot product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089297/formula-of-the-gradient-of-vector-dot-product)

$$\boldsymbol{a} \times \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \! \times \boldsymbol{b} \bigr)
= \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{a} \: - \: \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr)$$

or

$$\boldsymbol{a} \times \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \! \times \boldsymbol{b} \bigr)
= \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{a} \: - \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla} \bigr) \boldsymbol{b}$$

or

$$\bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{b} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{a} = \: \bigl( \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla} \bigr) \boldsymbol{b} \: + \: \boldsymbol{a} \times \bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \! \times \boldsymbol{b} \bigr)$$

I hope now it’s easy enough for everyone to get similar relations for $\bigl( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{a} \bigr) \! \cdot \boldsymbol{b}$ and “yes” for question *Are these equivalent?*

Comment: for a x (grad x b) = (grad b).a - a.(grad b), the term a.(grad b) doesn't make sense. Can vector be dotted with a matrix? I believe matrix can be dotted with a vector but not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Let us use the following index and shorthand notation.
$u_{,i}=\displaystyle{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}}$ . $x_1=x ,x_2=y, x_3=z$.  Einstein notation. Repeated index means summation over it,
and $[.]_i$ the i-th compnent of whatever is inside the square brackets $[]$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
  [\nabla (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b})]_i = (a_j b_j)_{,i} = a_{j,i}b_j + a_j b_{j,i}.
\end{eqnarray}

That is all, I do not see anything more complicated than this.
The two sums are matrix vector multiplications. Note that
$a_{j,i} b_j$ means the matrix $\partial a_j/\partial x_i$ times
the vector $b_j$.  You can write this in two different forms
\begin{eqnarray}
    (\nabla \mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{b}= (\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{a} =
 \left ( 
  \begin{array}{c}
    \displaystyle{b_1 \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x} + 
      b_2 \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial y} + b_ 3 \frac{\partial
    a_1}{\partial z}} \\ \\
    \displaystyle{b_1 \frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x} + 
      b_2 \frac{\partial a_2}{\partial y} + b_3 \frac{\partial
    a_2}{\partial z}} \\ \\
    \displaystyle{b_1 \frac{\partial a_3}{\partial x} + 
      b_2 \frac{\partial a_3}{\partial y} + b_3 \frac{\partial
    a_3}{\partial z}}
  \end{array}
  \right )
\end{eqnarray}
Where the symbol $\nabla \mathbf{a}$ means a matrix. The matrix whose rows are gradients of the components $a_1,a_2,a_3$ respectively. To be more precise the vector $\mathbf{b}$ on the left side is a column vector and that on the center is a row vector, so we can call the vector on the center instead $\mathbf{b}^T$ or transposed of the column vector $\mathbf{b}$, the whole expression in the center should be transposed as well...but this is a minor detail.
I do not see any difference between these two things. So we can say
\begin{eqnarray}
 \nabla (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}) = (\nabla \mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{b} = (\mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{b} + (\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{a}. 
\end{eqnarray}

I do not see where the curl $(\nabla \times)$ enter in this analysis.
Can someone point out an example where if we do not add the curl terms we get different values on the left and on the right?

Comment: The problem is with the transpose. $\nabla(a\cdot b)_i = a_{j,i}b_j+a_jb_{j,i}$ has a fixed index (no sum) for differentiation, like $\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x}b_1+\frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x}b_2+\frac{\partial a_3}{\partial x}b_3$ . This is the first component of the matrix product $J_a^Tb$ (using the Jacobian). The directional derivative $(b\cdot\nabla)a=J_ab$ has first component $\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x}b_1+\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial y}b_2+\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial z}b_3$. This is a sum over the differentiating index, $a_{i,j}b_j\neq a_{j,i}b_j$.