# Losing a curl in vector identity

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Considering

$$\nabla (\frac{1}{2} \vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$

The full identity has some cross product terms. But, when I try and work from this expression by itself with the summation convention I get the following (wrong) derivation

$$= \partial_i(\frac{1}{2} A_j A_j)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}(A_j\partial_i A_j + A_j\partial_i A_j)$$
$$=\vec{A} \cdot \nabla \vec{A}$$

Clearly, the cross terms have not popped up (and I very much know the standard method of starting with the cross terms) but why have they gone? Where have I implicitly assumed $\nabla \times \vec{A} = 0$?

Comment: Is that last line right?   $A_j\partial_i A_j$ not $A_j\partial_j A_i$

Comment: Yeah. Swapping the index would require a kronecker delta.

Answer (score 1):

You do not assume that $\nabla\times\vec A=0$. But you have $$\vec A\times(\nabla\times\vec A)=0$$For more detailed derivation of this result, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496060/gradient-of-a-dot-product)